# Running black causes error "This float doesn't have a leading digit"

Tags: python, flake8, pyproject.toml

When I try to run black on a specific file of my python project using `black a_file.py`, I get the following error:

```
 Error reading configuration file: This float doesn't have a leading digit (line 19 column 1 char 205)
```

Below is my pyproject.toml file:

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 88
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | buck-out
  | build
)/
'''

[flake8]
max-line-length = 88
max-complexity = 18
select = B, C, E, F, W, T4, B9
ignore = E203, E266, E501, W503, F403, F401
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: With the newest version of black and its dependencies, I get `Error: Could not open file '/Users/.../pyproject.toml': Error reading configuration file: Invalid value (at line 19, column 10)`. This seems to be an issue of the TOML parser, not necessarily black or flake8.

Comment: Indeed just `import tomli;tomli.load(open("pyproject.toml", "rb"))` is enough to trigger the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue of your `pyproject.toml` file using incorrect syntax. For example, a line such as `select = B, C, E, F, W, T4, B9` is INI-syntax – in TOML the equivalent would be `select = "B, C, E, F, W, T4, B9"` or `select = ["B", "C", "E", "F", "W", "T4", "B9"]`.

However, [`flake8` does not yet support `pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/issues/234) to begin with. Simply remove its configuration from the file.

> #### [Configuration Locations](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration-locations)
>
> Flake8 supports storing its configuration in your project in one of setup.cfg, tox.ini, or .flake8.